# linux как прочитать с файла utf16 и вывести его в консоль?

Tags: c++, linux, utf-8, utf16le

У меня есть файл с вот таким содержанием:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть тут 2 байта на один символ, значит это `utf16`.

У меня есть вот такой код:

```
String str;
ByteArray bstr;
bstr.Resize(size);
str.resize(size/2);
device.read((char*)bstr.GetData(), size);
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
{
     unsigned short res = bstr[i];
     res <<= 8;
     res |= bstr[i + 1];
     str[i/2] = res;
}

std::cout <<str;
```

`device` - это объект типа ifstream
`ByteArray` - это динамический массив unsigned char.
`String` - это `typedef std::string String;`
`size` - это размер файла.

В результате я получаю строку MainClass, так, как я и хотел, но если в файле будут юникод символы, например русские буквы, то результат будет неверный. Например запишем в файл строку "Привет мир!":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь результат этого кода: @825B <8@!

В процессе отладки я понял, что на 10 строчке приведенного вам кода в переменную res записывается большое число, а на 11 строчке скорее всего переполнение и это странно, ведь char должен уметь хранить юникод. Что не так с моим кодом и как его исправить?

Comment: *"ведь char должен уметь хранить юникод"* - char может хранить только ascii

Comment: @user7860670 а как линукс выводит utf8 в консоль?

Comment: Обычно можно рассчитывать лишь на вывод ascii. А при выводе utf8 массив char будет рассматриваться как буфер с бинарными данными, где символы могут занимать несколько char сразу. При попытке хранить в char символы юникода будет возникать ошибка, что символьный литерал не может быть присвоен без отбрасывания части данных.

Comment: @user7860670 так как мне решить мою проблему?

Comment: Ну если хотите utf16 выводить в utf8, то следует поставить библиотеку ICU и преобразовать исходный текст в нужную кодировку.

Comment: Считайте в utf16 строку (`std::u16string`) и запустите конвертор на utf8 (`std::string`). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302506/stdu32string-conversion-to-from-stdstring-and-stdu16string#31302660